# How can I modify or eliminate the mouse pointer while recording the iOS Simulator with QuickTime Player?

Tags: mouse, quicktime, xcode-simulator, video-capture

I would like to use QuickTime Player to create a screen recording of the iOS Simulator running an app. I need to simulate taps on the simulator with the mouse, but I don't want the standard arrow mouse pointer in the recording. An alternate appearance of the mouse pointer (such as a circle to represent the tip of a finger) would be preferable to hiding the mouse pointer entirely (I still need to see where it is so I can use the app correctly).

What options do I have for modifying or eliminating the mouse pointer on OS X? My machine is running Lion 10.7.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using ScreenFlow for my video. It allows me to change the mouse cursor into a white or black circle, with a varying level of opacity. It's exactly what I need.

Comment: Yeah, not paying $129 for that.

Answer (score 1):

I was also looking for a way of changing the cursor but I couldn't find anything. At the end I used Mousecape and added a custom cursor that resembles a finger shadow. I compiled the steps I followed here -> https://medium.com/@castillejoale/changing-mouse-cursor-in-xcode-simulator-72f768f5b434

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue as well.
I am trying to take a screen capture of my interactive prototype done in FramerJS.

If you are doing a HTML prototype, you could replace your cursor with an image. I have tested many sizes and it seems that the smallest size you can go is 3px by 3px. Any smaller than that, Quick Time will become unresponsive. Not sure why.

So yea, a small little cursor dot that is hardly noticeable.